# Compilation Error: solution.c:20:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token {

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, token, identifier

Unexpected error is occuring, Kindly help to resolve

```
/*Program to delete the nth Node from the Linked List*/
```

see the code piece here:

http://pastebin.com/esgv41aC

Comment: Hello ! Please add your code in stackoverflow not via pastbin. Thanks.

Comment: `void Insert(int data, int n);  //insert the data in the list at given position n;
    {` remove `;`, `Print` ditto.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: That is no C (using `new`).

Comment: When I try to post in code section, only 1 line is getting posted, I am not able to fix it or understand why its happening, Thats why i used pastebin, Can't copy paste my code in one whole go. Any leads to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the name of the `struct` here:

```
struct{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

It should be

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Another problem is that you use `new` which is a C++ operator to allocate memory. In C, use `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate memory. Don't forget to check is return value to check if was successful in allocating memory.

Also, here

```
if (temp1 ==1)
```

You compare a pointer with an `int`. This is wrong. I don't know what you are trying to do here...